# how to compare two csv files in powershell without specifying properties

Tags: file, powershell, csv, comparison

I have two csv files:

```
ipaddress,port
10.140.11.1,80
10.140.11.2,80
```

```
ipaddress,port
10.140.11.1,80
10.140.11.2,8008
```

The question is how to compare the files in powershell. I have already tried this:

```
$file1 = import-csv "csvfile1.csv"
$file2 = import-csv "csvfile2.csv"
Compare-Object $file1 $file2 -IncludeEqual
```

The result is as those two files were equal.

It works as expected if I specify the particular property, e.g:

```
Compare-Object $file1 $file2 -IncludeEqual -Property port
```

How to compare the csv files without specifying the properties. Let's say I would like to compare all properties in the csv file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can obtain the list of CSV column properties via `Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty`, then pass that list to `Compare-Object`.

```
# get list of CSV properties
$props1 = $file1 | gm -MemberType NoteProperty | select -expand Name | sort | % {"$_"}
$props2 = $file2 | gm -MemberType NoteProperty | select -expand Name | sort | % {"$_"}

# first check that properties match (can omit this step if you know for sure they will be)
if(Compare-Object $props1 $props2)
{
    throw "Properties are not the same! [$props1] [$props2]"
}
# pass properties list to Compare-Object
else
{
    Compare-Object $file1 $file2 -Property $props1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer by latkin will not work.
You will get the following exception:

Compare-Object : Cannot convert System.Management.Automation.PSObject to one of the following types {System.String, System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock}.
At line:8 char:19
+     Compare-Object <<<<  $file1 $file2 -Property $props1
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Compare-Object], NotSupportedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DictionaryKeyUnknownType,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CompareObjectCommand

It seems that one cannot pass a variable for -Property. It has to be a comma-seperated list of NoteProperties and it cannot be enclosed in single or double quotes.

I've been looking for a way to do this same thing and I still haven't found a way...

Comment: It appears that this error happens in PowerShell version 2, but not in PowerShell version 3

Comment: I edited the answer by latkin to fix the issue.  The | % {"$_"} will convert the list into a list of strings, not PSObjects.  That was the problem.