# Powershell to look in one CSV file to remove in another CSV file

Tags: powershell, csv

I have two CSV file, a.csv have

```
serial;address
45ADSAWR;B468ASDAS678
41ADGASR;1467ASSAS276
....
```

The b.csv file have

```
address
B234ASDGASD5
A454SGKIASD6
.....
```

That I trying to do is read the address in b.csv file and remove the line that have same address in a.csv file

The a.csv file have 380 lines and the b.csv file have 50 so when the script create c.csv file it going to have 330 lines of serial/address

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: post what have you tried instead of how to do!

Comment: I have try to use Excel because it have some good compare but have not find any that looks it going to work for me. Same with powershell I have search here and use google but what I have see that the problem is that I have one column and two in the other, The close I have got is this but only works if I have one columne
https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/370582-powershell-remove-line-from-csv-if-value-exists-in-another-csv

Comment: Now it start to look my way :)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17934542/how-to-compare-two-csv-files-in-powershell-without-specifying-properties

when I use and edit the code

    $file1 = import-csv "a.csv"
    $file2 = import-csv "b2.csv"
    Compare-Object $file1 $file2 -IncludeEqual -Property address

it can see the diffrent but it just write out the address, I need the serial too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the first file into a second variable using `Import-Csv`.

```
$a = Import-Csv 'a.csv' -Delimiter ';'
```

Read the second file and expand the address field, so you get an array with just the values. Assign that to another variable.

```
$b = Import-Csv 'b.csv' | Select-Object -Expand 'address'
```

Check `$a` for records whose `address` field does not match a value in `$b`. Export the result back to a CSV.

```
$a | Where-Object {
    $b -notcontains $_.address
} | Export-Csv 'c.csv' -Delimiter ';'
```

---

For better performance make `$b` a hashtable instead of an array

```
$b = @{}
Import-Csv 'b.csv' | ForEach-Object {
    $b[$_.address] = $true
}
```

and check for the absence of an address with a hashtable lookup.

```
$a | Where-Object {
    -not $b.ContainsKey($_.address)
} | Export-Csv 'c.csv' -Delimiter ';'
```

Comment: Ahh yes now I understand. I did just edit the code a little and now I got the info I need to have. Of course I can use a array to read the info and after in a loop compare and and the sametime write to c.csv. Why did not I think about that. AHHHH I'm to tired, need to go and eat and THANK YOU ALOT